# How does my view know what type of data is being returned using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I created a project to test DI in MVC 4. Yeah, that was the easy part. I have a controller that looks like this.

```
public class CompanyManagementController : Controller
{
     private ICompanyService companyService;

     public CompanyManagementController(ICompanyService companyService)
     {
         this.companyService = companyService;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         return View(companyService.GetCurrentCompanies());
     }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to tell the view Index.cshtml that I have this List that I am returning to it. When I have just a POCO it's easy. I did this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var company = new Company();
    return View(company);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Company company)
{
    using(var context = new InventoryContext())
    {
        context.Companies.Add(company);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View("Create");
}
```

That was super easy because I just said

```
@model MvcInventoryManager.Models.Company
```

in the Create.cshtml file.

Any hints? What I want to do is be able to loop through the list of companies that get returned.

Thanks!

Comment: You're sending a list to the view and you're unsure of the `model`? If so then just change your model to `IEnumerable<T>`.  `@model IEnumerable<MvcInventoryManager.Models.Company>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the return type of `companyService.GetCurrentCompanies()`?  That would be the type you'd want to use for binding the `Model` in the view.  For example, if the type is `IEnumerable<Company>` then in your view you would declare this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcInventoryManager.Models.Company>
```

That way the type of the `Model` property would match what's being passed to the view and you could loop through the `Model`:

```
foreach (var company in Model)
```

Comment: Right! Duh, I mean it seems so obvious when you point it out - then my Jquery ajax function still posts to Create() and I just change it to return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

after declaring your model in the view just loop through it like so:

```
@foreach (var company in Model)
{ 
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => company.companyID) 
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => company.CompanyName) 
}
```